# How to create specific type of Dropdown Menu in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dialog

I want to create a Drop menu like this one:

[image]

How can I create something like this a simple way? Doesn't matter how, it coudl be server side, javascript, jquery or any other library, does anyone know of a library that would allow me to create this type of dialog?

note: this dropdown/dialog/ or tooltip is opened whenever the user clicks the green (+) button.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the source for the screen shot you posted? That should give you a good idea of how they did it.

Comment: it's actually an image I found not a screenshot I took from a website.

Answer (score 1):

This type of effect is called a Fixed Tooltip. The plugin Tooltipster seems to offer the functionality you're looking for (http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/). Just create a Tooltip, set "interactive: true", "trigger: click", and "position: right" and style it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dialog box, the best tool (IMHO) is [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

About the dropdown, it's just styled with CSS. You may need help from a designer.